# How can I convert a filepath to a short (8.3) path?

Tags: java

Is there any way to convert a long filepath into a short ([8.3 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename)) directly through the Java API (i.e. not using the command line)?

For example, it should convert `C:\Program Files\Java` to `C:\Progra~1\Java`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893284/how-to-get-short-filenames-in-windows-using-java

Comment: Not duplicate , I am looking for solution without command line.

Comment: Path to be converted is "C:\Program Files\Java" to something like C:\Program~\Java

Comment: Uhm ... Why? Which API/tool can't handle "long" file names now?

Answer (score 1):

You can use for example [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/releases) as described in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28562559/how-to-solve-jdk-issue-unexpected-at-this-time#28562923)

**Java using JNA**

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;

public class LongToShort {

    public static String GetShortPathName(String path) {
        char[] result = new char[256];
        Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetShortPathName(path, result, result.length);
        return Native.toString(result);
    }

    // usage: java LongToShort "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45"
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(GetShortPathName(args[0]));
    }
}
```