# How to fix 'Java ... was unexpected at this time' when invoking VS 2017 build tools from Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

I have Jenkins freestyle jobs that successfully invoke msbuild jobs using the VS 2015 tools by declaring environment variable:

```
VSMSBUILDCMD_14_0="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\Tools\\VsMSBuildCmd.bat"
```

and setting the environment by calling from a bat step:

```
call %VSMSBUILDCMD_14_0%
```

However, if I try to do similar using the VS 2017 tools I get an expected error:

```
VSMSBUILDCMD_14_1="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\Common7\\Tools\\VsMSBuildCmd.bat"

call %VSMSBUILDCMD_14_1%

c:\jenkins\workspace\aa_test>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\VsMSBuildCmd.bat"

\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin"" was unexpected at this time.
```

I get the same result even if I use shortened directory names:

```
VSMSBUILDCMD_14_1="C:\\PROGRA~2\\MIB055~1\\2017\\BuildTools\\Common7\\Tools\\VsMSBuildCmd.bat"

CALL %VSMSBUILDCMD_14_1%

CALL "C:\PROGRA~2\MIB055~1\2017\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\VsMSBuildCmd.bat" 
\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin"" was unexpected at this time.
```

This question may be related: [How to solve JDK issue unexpected at this time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28562559/how-to-solve-jdk-issue-unexpected-at-this-time)

but I haven't managed to fix my problem.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score -1):

You probably have a JAVA_HOME environment variable set to c:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161. Try using shortnames with that.

set JAVA_HOME="c:\PROGRA~1\Java\jre1.8.0_161"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\VsMSBuildCmd.bat"

Comment: Hi Sean, JAVA_HOME is not set: '>set JAVA_HOME' gives 
'Environment variable JAVA_HOME not defined'

Comment: maybe your PATH? It looks like something being called from VsMSBuildCmd.bat is not handling spaces correctly.

Comment: Thanks, yes clearing PATH fixed the problem.  Perhaps one of the Java paths there was causing it.  If you want to add this as another answer, I'll accept it.